# How to prevent password expiration for API user?

Tags: rest-api, passwords

Every 3 months, the password for our API user expires. We've tried turning off password expiration for that user, but it doesn't seem to do anything. The password still expires every 3 months.

What could be causing the password to expire even though it's not set to expire? The passwords for other, non-API users within Salesforce don't ever expire, so it's baffling as to why it does for this API user, even with password expiration turned off!

Comment: Is there anything specific about that user? Profile/Permissionsets assigned?

Comment: Just to be clear, did you assign the "Password Never Expires" permission to the API user via a profile or permission set?

Comment: I don't have admin access and must rely on another person to verify for me. So, I'm not able to answer your questions, but I'll find out and report back. By your questions, it sounds like there is more than one way to prevent password expiration, which is promising.